# Calling a function doesn't execute the print statement inside that function

Tags: c

Why is it that my first block of code doesn't output anything while the 2nd block does print out "hi"? I suspect that the program never goes into the test() function in the first block, but I don't know why that happens and how I should fix it.

P.S. I know that my codes don't really make any sense such as that the return value of the functions should be char *. This is because I haven't completed the function and I am still at the stage of testing what I have written. I think the return value of char * shouldn't be the reason for my problem, but do let me know if it is!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* test(char **strs, int strs_sz){
  printf("%s", "hi");
}

int main(void){
    char *arg[] = {"XX", "YY", "ZZ"};
    char *all = test(arg, 1); 
    printf("%s\n", all);
    free(all);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* fcn(char **para){
    printf("%s", "hi");
}

int main(void){
  char *arg[] = {"XX", "YY", "ZZ"};
  char *s = fcn(arg); 
}
```

Comment: Put a `\n` after `%s`. I suspect the text is getting stuck in a buffer

Comment: @Carcigenicate It worked! Would you mind elaborating a bit on what you meant by "the text is getting stuck in a buffer"? Why does it happen with the 1st block of the code, but not the 2nd? Or if you could refer me to any appropriate resources to learn about it?

Comment: @Cheryl The function test returns nothing.

Comment: The stdout is newline buffered by default iirc, which means the text sits in a buffer and will only be actually printed when a newline is encountered, or the buffer gets filled past a certain level. I'm not a C expert though, so I'm not sure of a good resource off the top of my head that covers that.

Comment: And, ya, your function doesnt return anything, but you're attempting to use `all`, which will have undefined results. You need to explicitly `return` data in order to return from a function. Printing != returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up what was already explained in the comments and fill in some blanks:

When using standard C library functions to work with files (`printf` actually works with a file `stdout`), the data is first cached in memory, and only written to the actual file when some condition is met:

- The file is closed
- The file is `fflush`ed.
- The memory buffer is full
- etc.

In case of `stdout`, this will happen when the `\n` character is printed or when your program exists and the file is closed.

However, in your first code snippet you try to dereference (use) a pointer `all`.
Since you did not write a `return` statement in your `test` function, it is impossible to predict what value will end up being stored in `all`.

So, your program most likely crashes unexpectedly, and thus the buffer never gets written to `stdout`.

You should never test incomplete functions!
At the very least, build up a skeleton code that makes the function legal, such as a dummy return statement.

Otherwise, you will encounter "undefined behavior", which is another way of saying your program will react in weird and unpredictable ways.